# Function expected error in IE 11 & Uncaught TypeError: uploadKycDocsLater is not a function in Chrome

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

Below is my part of code where I am getting error

```
if(whenToUploadKycDocs == "uploadNow"){             
    uploadKycDocsNow();
}else{              
    uploadKycDocsLater();   //error here
}
```

Below is uploadKycDocsLater()

```
function uploadKycDocsLater(){
uploadKycDocsLater = "uploadLater";
$.ajax({
    url : uploadKycdocsLaterUrl,
    type : 'POST',
    datatype : 'json',
    data : $('#uploadKyc-form').serialize(),
    async : false,
    success : function(uploadKycDocsLaterData) {             
     if(uploadKycDocsLaterData != "redirect"){
        processJson(uploadKycDocsLaterData);                    
        if(numberOfApplicants == "applicant-one"){
             $("#firstApplicantDetails").show();
             $("#secondApplicantDetails").hide();
             $("#thirdApplicantDetails").hide();

             $("#applicantTwoPreview").hide();
            $("#applicantThreePreview").hide();
         }
        if(numberOfApplicants == "applicant-two"){
             $("#firstApplicantDetails").show();
             $("#secondApplicantDetails").show();
             $("#thirdApplicantDetails").hide();    

             $("#applicantThreePreview").hide();
        }
        if(numberOfApplicants == "applicant-three"){
             $("#firstApplicantDetails").show();
             $("#secondApplicantDetails").show();
             $("#thirdApplicantDetails").show();
        }
        $("#collapse8").collapse("show");
        $("#collapse7").collapse("hide");
            if(activeTabIndex >= currentTabIndex){ 
                currentTabIndex = 7;
            }
        }else{
             window.location.reload(true);  
        }
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});

}
```

Clearly as you can see uploadKycDocsLater() is a function which I am calling from am if condition, there is another function uploadKycDocsNow() which is working fine. It also has code similar to uploadKycDocsLater()
What might be the error ?